# Analysis of a Closed Convex Set in Function Space with No Minimal Norm Element

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

Hello I am new to real analysis and while I was studying I came upon this specific question which has troubled me

Let C [0,1] be the space of continuous functions in [0,1] with the sup norm. Let M = ${f \in [0,1] : (\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{2}} f - \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} f = 1}$. Show that M is a closed convex set which contains no minimal norm element

What i have thought to do to prove that M is a closed set is to prove that if $f_n$​ is a sequence in M converging to some g, then show that g is also in M

To do that we suppose $f_n$ is a sequence in M converging to g in the sup norm. This means that $||f_n - g||_{\infty} \rightarrow0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

$f_n\in M$ so $\left(\int _1^{\frac{1}{2}}f_n-\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1f_n\:\right)=\int _1^{\frac{1}{2}}g-\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1g\:\:=1$ so g is also in M

Is my solution correct or am i missing something i seem to be a bit lost

Comment: Your solution is not a solution, because you only considered the easier one-third of the problem.
Also, why are you writing the integral with its limits reversed?

Comment: Did you intend to write $M = \left\{f \in C[0,1] \mid \int_0^{1/2} f - \int_{1/2}^1f = 1\right\}$ instead?  (there are a couple typos I have fixed, but one of them is pervasive in your question)

Comment: Show that $f \mapsto \int_0^{1/2} f - \int_{1/2}^1f $ is continuous and linear, hence the inverse of a closed convex set ($\{1\}$ here) is closed and convex. To show that there